# trouble with listing items in html view - global variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I´m new to RoR

I have a strange problem  - I´m trying to render a list of "Product Scale" objects by name

```
<ul>
<%= @product_scales.each do |p| %>
<li><%= p.scale_name%></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

The list is printed out alright, but for some reason so are the class instance names,
so it looks like this:

Scale:

- local
- regional
- #< ProductScale:0x12ad625b0># < ProductScale:0x12ad60418>

In my controller it looks like this:

```
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
@product_scales =ProductScale.findByProductId(params[:id])
```

I also tried

```
@product_scales = ProductScale.findByProductId(params[:id]).map{|p| p.scale_name}
```

and in the html.erb file:

```
<li><%= p %></li>
```

This gave the following:

- local
- regional
- localregional

Here it looks like the `to_s` method for the `@product_scales` object is being called and the result - localregional - displayed on the page.

I can't figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that's not a typo in your code posted above, you have:

`<%= @product_scales.each do |p| %>`

The <%= will cause it to output, you need to use:

`<% @product_scales.each do |p| %>`